# how to store python float in SQL database

Tags: python, sql, floating-point, decimal, precision

In python3, I mainly use float or np.float32/64 and when it comes to store it into a database, even if SQL type is Numeric/Decimal we end up with 0.400000000000021 or something like that instead of 0.4
It may be a problem if such data is accessed from another application.

Working only with decimal.Decimal in python isn't an answer for us, since we heavely make use of pandas, and Decimal is not supported.
A solution would be to cast float to Decimal just before inserting into SQL (SQL Server in our case but it's a detail). And then back from Decimal to float after SELECT.
Do you have another (and nicer) way to handle such issue ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the value of your float isn't 0.4, because there is no value in either `float32` or `float64` (or Python native `float`, which is usually the same as `float64`) that's 0.4. The closest `float64` to 0.4 that is 0.400000000000021, which is exactly what you've got.

Since that's the closest `float` value there is to 0.4, if you ask Python to convert it to a string (e.g., `print(f)`), it'll be friendly and give you the string `0.4`.

But when you pass it to a database… Well, it actually depends on which database interface library you're using. With some, it will call `repr`, which would give you `'0.4'` (at least in Python 3.x), so you're asking the database to store the float value of the string `'0.4'`. But with others, it will pass the float value directly as a C `double`, so you're asking the database to store the float value `0.400000000000021`.

---

So, what should you do?

- Do you want to use this database with other code that will be reading the values as strings and then converting them to something like `Decimal` or `float80` or `decimal64` or some other type? Then you almost certainly want to set a SQL data type like `DECIMAL(12, 6)` that matches your actual precision, and let the database take care of it. (After all, there is no difference between `0.4` rounded to 6 decimal places and `0.400000000000021` rounded to 6 decimal places.)
- Do you want to do math inside the database itself? Same as above.
- Otherwise? Do nothing.

Seriously, if the other code that's going to use this database is just going to read the values as `float64`, or read them as strings and convert them to `float64` (or `float32`), they are going to end up with `0.400000000000021` no matter what you do, so don't do anything.

Also, consider this: if the difference between `0.4` and `0.400000000000021` is going to make any difference for any of your code, then your code is already broken by using `float64`, before you even get to the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wan't/need the precision, you can use `np.round(array,roundto)`

Comment: I tried python standard round() but doesn't help since it returns a float. I may be wrong but np.round() will return an np.float so problem is still there. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define decimal places in SQL, e.g.: `decimal(8,2)`

Answer (score 0):

I've used round(float (...),2) to insert data in sql and in last case have changed types in sql to **float**