# pyodbc insert decimal Error converting data type nvarchar to float

Tags: sql-server-2012, decimal, pyodbc

Can't understand, which problem can cause this:

Error converting data type nvarchar to float.

I'm getting data by api from one software and would like to insert this data in sql database.
here are the types of the data recieved in dataframe
[image]
What I see in profiler.. and suspect, that the problem in decimal or int

[image]

I've tried replace, but then I get the same result and

```
VALUES(?,?,convert(int,replace(?,',','.')),?,?, convert(decimal(18,2),replace(?,',','.')),?,?,?,?,?) END"
```

Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

```
for t in tuples:
    print(t)
    use = t[0]
    btiId = t[1]
    area = None
    if t[2] is not None:
        area = round(float(str(t[2])[:str(t[2]).find('.')+2]),2)
    else:
        area = None
    print(area)
    number = t[5]
    name = t[3]
    building = None
    floor = None
    premise = None
    if t[8] is not None:
        building = t[8][0]['name']
    else:
        bulding = None
    if t[9] is not None:
        floor = t[9][0]['name']
    else:
        floor = None
    t = (btiId, building, floor, number, premise, name, area, area, area, 'BPS', 'Коммерческие', 'БПС',use, btiId,area,btiId)
    print(t)


    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    query = "IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[premises] WHERE btiId = ?) BEGIN \
    UPDATE [dbo].[premises] SET area = ? WHERE btiId = ? END \
    ELSE BEGIN INSERT INTO [dbo].[premises] ([building], [floor], [number], [premise], [name],\
    [area],[owner],[purpose],[ownershipCode],[used],[btiId])\
    VALUES(?,?,convert(int,?),?,?, case when isnumeric(?)=1 then convert(decimal(18,2),round(?,2)) else ? end,?,?,?,?,?) END"
    cursor.execute(query,t)
    cnxn.commit()
    cursor.close()
```

These are the columns of the table in SQL database
[image]

I've tried Decimal
and got next error:

Invalid precision value (0)

These are the values I print before using tuple in statement of pyodbc

> ('000a031d-adac-4e80-91bf-09626761a55a', 'M3', '-9300', 84.0, None,
> None, Decimal('8.9000000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625'),
> 'BPS', 'Коммерческие', 'БПС', None,
> '000a031d-adac-4e80-91bf-09626761a55a',
> Decimal('8.9000000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625'),
> '000a031d-adac-4e80-91bf-09626761a55a')

when I used round, the value looked normal - 8.9,
but the error returned

here is the link to the similar question, but I can't see ultimate solution
[how to store python float in SQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49522441/how-to-store-python-float-in-sql-database/76201220?noredirect=1#comment134380086_76201220)

Comment: What is your SQL query?

provide with sample data

Comment: The 2 values you highlight in the image aren't `nvarchar` values; they aren't the cause of the error.

Comment: I've added the names of columns in the database table. There are only three fields of decimal and int types. The query itself is given in the code - if exists .. with given id, then begin update... end else insert .. almost all the attributes (except dates) end end

Comment: I've found the closest to my problem answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49522441/how-to-store-python-float-in-sql-database but I suppose I've already tried some options

Answer (score 0):

I've changed decimal and int types to **float**

```
area = float(round(Decimal(t[2]),2))
```